# Windows Phone 8.1 play a sound effect in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a simple 2d game using WPF where the game objects need to emit a sound when they hit the walls of the screen, but I can't find anything that lets me play a sound effect in Windows Phone 8.1.

In Windows Phone 8 I was using the SoundEffect class from XNA, but I don't think XNA is supported in 8.1 any longer.  Is there any equivalent class I can use?

Comment: I assume you mean a Universal App, WPF is a completely different technology than Windows 8 Store Applications / Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<MediaElement>` with [MediaElement.AudioCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.audiocategory.aspx) set to `ForegroundOnlyMedia`

If you want more controlled sound playback, you'll need to use DirectX.